# Make a button submittable more than once

Tags: javascript, html

So I found a script that can generate your link when you want to, here it is (credits to the owner!)

```js
function CreateAffiliateLink(F) {
  var findstring = "XXXXX";
  var ts = 'var replacewith=document.' + F.name + '.AffCode.value';
  eval(ts);
  if (replacewith.length < 1) {
    return;
  }
  var re = new RegExp(findstring, "g")
  for (i = 0; i < F.length; i++) {
    var s = new String(F.elements[i].value);
    if (s.length > 0) {
      var newstr = s.replace(re, replacewith);
      F.elements[i].value = newstr;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="me">
  <p>
    Type your affiliate code in the box and click the button:
    <input type="text" name="AffCode" size="17">
    <input type="button" value="Personalize links with my affiliate code" onClick="CreateAffiliateLink(this.form)">
  </p>
  <p>
    Image link:<br>
    <textarea name="a" cols="46" rows="3" wrap="off"> 
    <a href="http://example.com/master/#XXXXX 
    <img src="http://example.com/image.jpg"> 
    </a> 
    </textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    An ezine text link:<br>
    <input type="text" name="b" size="46" value="http://example.com/master/#XXXXX">
  </p>
</form>
```

But right now, when I use it, I have to refresh everytime I want to put a new value. I wanted to find a way on how I can generate more than once without having to refresh the page.

I tried editing some part of it but it's still only usable once. Is there a way to change that?

Comment: Why do you need `eval()`? `var replaceWith = document[F.name].AffCode.value;`

Comment: Actually, you don't even need all that. `var replaceWith = F.affCode.value;`

Comment: I don't see anything in that code that replaces links. It replaces `F.elements[i].value`, and `.value` only exists for input fields, not links. Did you mean `F.elements[i].href`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because findstring is always 'XXXXX' (it looks for value, which changes after click).

Replace old code with:

```
var findstring = "XXXXX";
function CreateAffiliateLink(F) {
    var replacewith = F.AffCode.value;
    if (replacewith.length < 1) return;
    var re = new RegExp(findstring, "g")
    for (i = 0; i < F.length; i++) {
        var s = F.elements[i].value.toString();
        if (s.length > 0) {
            var newstr = s.replace(re, replacewith);
            F.elements[i].value = newstr;
            findstring = replacewith;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That works great unless your affiliate code is something that already exists in the url, like "example", in which case it will replace the "example" in example.com as well.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it only works once is because it's looking for `XXXXX` in the URL, and replacing that with the affiliate code. But after you do a replacement, the URL no longer has `XXXXX`.

Use a more general regular expression that will match the `master/#` in the URL, and replace everything after it.

```js
function CreateAffiliateLink(F) {
  var replacewith=F.AffCode.value;
  if (replacewith.length < 1) {
    return;
  }
  replacewith = 'master/#' + replacewith;
  var re = /master\/#\w+/g;
  for (i = 0; i < F.length; i++) {
    var s = new String(F.elements[i].value);
    if (s.length > 0) {
      var newstr = s.replace(re, replacewith);
      F.elements[i].value = newstr;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="me">
  <p>
    Type your affiliate code in the box and click the button:
    <input type="text" name="AffCode" size="17">
    <input type="button" value="Personalize links with my affiliate code" onClick="CreateAffiliateLink(this.form)">
  </p>
  <p>
    Image link:<br>
    <textarea name="a" cols="46" rows="3" wrap="off"> 
    <a href="http://example.com/master/#XXXXX"> 
    <img src="http://example.com/image.jpg"> 
    </a> 
    </textarea>
  </p>
  <p>
    An ezine text link:<br>
    <input type="text" name="b" size="46" value="http://example.com/master/#XXXXX">
  </p>
</form>
```